# How to Divide the Contents of a TkInter Entry With a Number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been trying to figure out how to divide the contents of a TkInter entry box with a number (a float, to be precise). I looked it up on [Google](https://www.ixquick.com/do/dsearch?query=how%20to%20divide%20the%20contents%20of%20a%20tkinter%20entry%20with%20a%20number&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english), and I found nothing that answered my question, other than doing `.get()` for *getting a number* from a entry. I want to *have a number already there* (or have a static variable) that I can divide to get the results I need.

P.S. Here's the website results I saw before I posted this question:

[image]

[Results of search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A4DF.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What do you mean by divide the entry? You want to split it into two entries? The user will type a number and click a button, and then what will happen? Explain better.

Comment: Use a `DoubleVar` as the variable.

Comment: Sorry about that @nosklo. What I mean is I want to use a number (just a number) and have the float value from the TkInter entry box, and divide the number by the float value from the TkInter entry box. Is that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To divide an input from entrybox using float:**
if you want entrybox to be in int form not float use int()

```
num = 3.0
temp = float(entrybox.get())
divided = temp / num
```

**or divide/split a string:**

```
temp = entrybox.get().split(" ")# enter what to split by in speech marks
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is EXACTLY what I needed! +1

Comment: Im glad it helped