# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'DoubleVar'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a tkinter widget to enter vlaues with a  DoubleVar:

```
root=tk.Tk()

root.title("Defining parameter values") # window title
window=tk.Frame(root) # window setup
window.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=('n','w','e','s'))
window.columnconfigure(0,weight=1) # adjust window size
window.rowconfigure(0,weight=1) # automatically

# variable type definitions

Bt = tk.DoubleVar() #aquifer thickness (taken from model Aa)
Bt.set(200)

rc = tk.DoubleVar() #effective radius well casing (1.685), corrected for radius transponder (0.3)
rc.set(1.658)

Le = tk.DoubleVar() #effective screen length = b
Le.set(21)

Re = tk.DoubleVar() #effective radius slug test = effective radius well screen (see fetter p. 194)
Re.set(1.535)

rw = tk.DoubleVar() #effective radius well screen
rw.set(1.535)

d = tk.DoubleVar() #z-position of top of screen (positive direction downward)
d.set(20)

user_aniso = tk.DoubleVar()
user_aniso.set(0.1)

tk.Label(window,text="Aquifer thickness (m) = ").grid(row=4,column=1,sticky='e')
Bt_entry=tk.Entry(window,width=7,textvariable=Bt)
Bt_entry.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=('w','e'))
if Bt_entry in range(1,1000):
    Bt_entry == float(Bt.get())
else:
    Bt_entry == str(Bt)

#rc
tk.Label(window,text="rc(cm) = ").grid(row=5,column=1,sticky='e')
rc_entry=tk.Entry(window,width=7,textvariable=rc)
rc_entry.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=('w','e'))
if rc_entry in range(1,10):
    rc_entry == float(rc.get())
else:
    rc_entry == str(rc)

#Le=b
tk.Label(window, text="b(cm) = ").grid(row=6,column=1,sticky='e')
Le_entry=tk.Entry(window,width=7,textvariable=Le)
Le_entry.grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=('w','e'))
if Le_entry in range(20,24):
    Le_entry == float(Le.get())
else:
    Le_entry == str(Le)


#Re
tk.Label(window, text="Re(cm) = ").grid(row=7,column=1,sticky='e')
Re_entry=tk.Entry(window,width=7,textvariable=Re)
Re_entry.grid(row=7,column=2,sticky=('w','e'))
if Re_entry in range(1,10):
    Re_entry == float(Re.get())
else:
    Re_entry == str(Re)


#rw
tk.Label(window, text="rw(cm) = ").grid(row=8,column=1,sticky='e')
rw_entry=tk.Entry(window,width=7,textvariable=rw)
rw_entry.grid(row=8,column=2,sticky=('w','e'))
if rw_entry in range(1,10):
    rw_entry == float(rw.get())
else:
    rw_entry == str(rw)

#d
tk.Label(window, text="d(cm) = ").grid(row=9,column=1,sticky='e')
d_entry=tk.Entry(window,width=7,textvariable=d)
d_entry.grid(row=9,column=2,sticky=('w','e'))
if d_entry in range(1,100):
    d_entry == float(d.get())
else:
    d_entry == str(d)

#aniso
tk.Label(window, text="Anisotropy ratio Kv/Kh = ").grid(row=10,column=1,sticky='e')
user_aniso_entry=tk.Entry(window,width=7,textvariable=user_aniso)
user_aniso_entry.grid(row=10,column=2,sticky=('w','e'))
if user_aniso in range(1,10):
    user_aniso_entry == float(user_aniso.get())
else:
    user_aniso_entry == str(user_aniso)

#ttk.Button(window,text="Please click here to check your values",command=validation).grid(row=11,column=2,sticky=E)
tk.Button(window,text="Save values",command=parameters).grid(row=12,column=2,sticky='e')
```

But after, using the variables to do calculation:

```
def calculateKhHvorslev(rc, rw, Le, Re, T0, T0plus, T0first, user_aniso):
    results = {}
    ps=(Le/rw)
    pss=(user_aniso/ps)
    psi = math.sqrt(pss)

#    print ('PSI ', psi, user_aniso)

    F = ((1/(2*psi)) + math.sqrt(1 + (1/(2*psi)**2)))
```

And

> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'DoubleVar'`

appears for the first calculation: `ps=(Le/rw)` (but probably as well for the next ones).

I'll tried to type float next to each variable .get but does not worked...

Comment: You said this didn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019798/how-to-divide-the-contents-of-a-tkinter-entry-with-a-number

Comment: No, I tried using float in variable.set(float(number)) and aswell in the variable_entry=float(variable.get)

Comment: And still says that there is an error in ps=(Le/rw) for using /. Can I use maybe another function t divide them?

Comment: No matter what I try, rw is always a DoubleVar and I can't calculate with it

Comment: To run the calculation rw must be numeric, an int or a float. The error message says its a tk.DoubleVar.  Use rw.get() to get the float value of the DoubleVar, probably in the call to the function rather than in the function itself. The question doesn't show where it's called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you show how you are calling the `calculateKhHvorslev` function?
The error message says that `Le` is an int and `re` is a DoubleVar.
Try `ps = Le/rw.get()`.

Comment: Yes thank you, indeed I applied Le.get() and rw.get() separately (outside the function) because I need them for others. And now it's working.